BASH - Find file with regex - Non-recursively delete number-only filenames in directory
I'm wanting to non-recursively delete all files in a directory where each filename contains only numbers, using only a single line of BASH.
I somehow accidentally ran a shell script with commented out file suffix variables, so I inundated my directory with over 1000 filenames that contain only numbers and no file extensions, with somewhere between 1 to 4 digits, like so:
1001   1010   1025   1039   1053   1064   1089   1107   1204   1300   1340   1420   1590   1701   1730   1806   302   406   480   604   704   820   19   1   73   8
Thankfully, my directory contains no valuable files that start with numbers, so I am okay to delete all files that start with numbers. I know that I could find all of these files using multiple BASH commands like are shown below (which I've proven does work), but I want a more elegant way to do so:
find . -name '[0-9]'
find . -name '[0-9][0-9]'
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

Sample output of last command by itself:
./1019
./1340
./1710
./1046

The find command is useful to me because I only have to append -delete after the command to delete the found files.
I'm not strictly opposed to somehow including shopt -s extglob (to enable extended globbing and maybe allow interpretation of a few more [idk?] characters by the shell) into the single line, but I don't know how that would be done, what side effects it may have on further commands I run, or how to stop that property being applied to future commands and causing unexpected issues.
If what I'm looking for is impossible, then I'm open to hearing possibilities or references using sed, awk, or a single line for/while loop.
Here are the single-liners I've tried so far (none of which work correctly):
find . -name '[0-9]+'
*This didn't throw an error, but it found nothing (it should've found lots of files in the current directory, as proven by ls).
find . -name '[0-9]([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?'
*This didn't throw an error, but it found nothing in the current directory.
*I added the parentheses to make it more visually clear that the 2nd, 3rd, and/or 4th digits can be absent.
*SiegeX's answer recommended to use -regex (with a special qualifier) instead of -name since -name uses the weaker glob formatting instead of regex.
find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '[0-9]([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?'
*I got the error find: paths must precede expression: `posix-extended'. Idk what the weird backtick followed by an apostrophe in the error is supposed to mean...
*John Kugelman's answer says the parentheses are supposed to be "escaped" (have a backslash before each parenthesis), so I'll just get rid of them since they were only there for visual-understanding reasons.
find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?'
*Same error as above
*According to John Kugelman's same answer, this is missing a full file path
find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '$pwd/[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?'
*Same error as above
find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '/home/currDir/[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?'
*Same error as above
find /home/currDir/ -regex -regextype posix-extended '/home/currDir/[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?'
*Same error as above
find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '[0-9]+'
*Same error as above
find . -regex -regextype '[0-9]+' posix-extended
*Different error!  Error: find: paths must precede expression: `[0-9]+'
find . -regex '[0-9]+' -regextype posix-extended
*No error, but didn't output any files it found either.
find . '[0-9]+' -regex -regextype posix-extended
*Error: find: paths must precede expression: `posix-extended'
find . -regex '[0-9]+'
*No error, but didn't output any files it found either.
find . '{0,999}'
*This recursively outputs ALL files in the directory and subdirectories. I don't want to delete any files in my subdirectories because those are the input files for my program, so this doesn't work. Also, it includes files that don't contain any numbers and numbers that are out of the specified range.
*Example output:
./1780
./407
./1800
./testfiles
./testfiles/simple.html
./testfiles/medium.html
./testfiles/hard.html
./1470
./1039
find: ‘{0,999}’: No such file or directory
find . '{0,9}{0,9}{0,9}$'
*Same output as above, except the last line is instead find: ‘{0,9}{0,9}{0,9}$’: No such file or directory.
find . -name '*[0-9]'
*Doesn't work because non-numeric characters are included. Example output:
./1107
./870
./1059
./testfiles3
./1023
./40

in find . -regex -regextype posix-extended '[0-9]([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?', note that -regex takes the next command line argument as the regex to match against, so this means to use -regextype as the regex, and then posix-extended is just a word, one that doesn't match any of the find expressions, so it errors out. (It assumes you meant that as a path to walk, but those have to be in front. Some other implemention might give a different error.) The weird backtick-singlequote combination is just an odd idea of starting and ending quotes.

If you are "okay to delete all files that start with numbers" why not just use a straightforward wildcard glob, rm [0-9]*?

No need for regexps,
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*[!0-9]*' -type f -delete

Non-recursively (and that applies for all find commands below), add -maxdepth 1 if supported, or change to:
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '*[!0-9]*' -type f -delete

(-delete being a non-standard but fairly common extension, a lot more common than your -regextype which is a GNU-only extension).
Would delete the files whose name are made only of digits (those other than the ones that contain at least one non-digit).
In zsh, you could also do:
rm -f -- **/<->(D.)

Non recursive:
rm -f <->(.)

Where <-> is a form of <1-123> without bound so matches any decimal integer number, and (D) to enable dotglob to also consider hidden files (such as .git/123) as find does, and the . qualifier as the equivalent of find's -type f.
To only delete the ones with 1 to 4 digits:
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*[!0-9]*' ! -name '?????*' -type f -delete

rm -f -- **/<0-9999>(D.)

Strictly speaking, <0-9999> would also match on 00002. See also **/[0-9](#c1,4)(D.) in zsh -o extendedglob to explicitly match 1 to 4 digits (similar to ksh93's {1,4}([0123456789])).
If you wanted to use GNU find's -regex, you'd need:
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{1,4}' -type f -delete

Bear in mind that:

-regex matches on the full path (like -path, not -name)
and the regexp is implicitly anchored at start and end so you need the .*/
Even more so than for -name, you want LC_ALL=C to be able to match arbitrary file paths (even those that can't be decoded as text in the user's locale), and for [0-9] to match on 0123456789 only.

With BSD find, use the -E option instead of the -regextype posix-extended predicate for extended regexps.
You could also have done:
LC_ALL=C find . '(' -name '[0-9]' -o -name '[0-9][0-9]' -o -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' -o -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' ')' -type f -delete

To match those 1, 2, 3, 4 digit file names with only one find invocation.
With bash -O dotglob -O failglob -O extglob -O globstar (assuming bash 5.0 or newer), you could also do:
export LC_ALL=C
rm -f -- **/[0-9]?([0-9]?([0-9]?([0-9])))

(though without the -type f equivalent as bash doesn't have glob qualifiers).
Bash with extglob implements a subset of ksh's extended glob operators, but not the {x,y}(...) one from ksh93, so here we use ksh88's ?(...) which is like {0,1}(...).
Remove the -O globstar and **/ for non-recursive.

in bash, one need to escape the ! otherwise bash will attempt to replace it with the latest command in history (on old bash at least?). '!' or \!

@OlivierDulac, not when on its own like that.

If this is only for the current directory, then use this to list the files:
export LC_ALL=C; shopt -s nullglob;
printf "%s\n" [0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

And either of these to delete it:

Run rm once per file:
for i in [0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ;
do
  rm "$i";
done

(Can be done in one line by just removing all the newlines)

Or if you have an xargs supporting -0, then use it to batch up executions of rm:
printf "%s\0" [0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | xargs -r0 rm



We could use a more complex pattern to reduce the repetition, but it's just a maximum of 4 digits. Easier and simpler to just copy-paste [0-9] a few times.

Beware that bash's [0-9] in most modern locales matches hundreds of characters beside 0123456789 even with globasciiranges on.

I concurr with @StéphaneChazelas remark: this approach without setting the locale to 'C' or equivalent, could potentially lead to numerous "other" files (of name's length 1-4) to be deleted, so this answer, as is, is dangerous.

@OlivierDulac ah, the irony. There are two answers here which ignore the "non-recursively" part of the question and will definitely end up deleting more files than the OP wants, and yet it's this one that's dangerous. Ah well, I'll add the locale.

@muru: fear not, I downvoted both (but was thinking duplicating my comment would be pointless ^^). I'll update (=take out the downvote) when you do  (I didn't see that the othre answer had also overlooked locale, so my comment said "this answer" instead of "these 2 answers", sorry for that)

@OlivierDulac ah, I see you missed the "non-recursively" part of my comment (and the question) too :D

I didn't miss it in the question, but I don't see any recursion in your answer?

@OlivierDulac there isn't - my point is that both of the other answers recurse, even though OP explicitly specified otherwise, and yet my answer was called dangerous when the others weren't.

Per default -regex uses emacs expression syntax. It works as you expect. But the regex must also match the directory. So the minimal search is:
$ find . -type f -regex '.*/[0-9]+'
./542356
./foo/123
./foo/1234
./foo/3

I recommend to add -type f to find only files.
When you are satisfied with the result, just add -delete and find will remove the found files.

You can match any file name consisting only of digits like this
find -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '(.*/)?[0-9]+'

The ERE handles file name paths that do not begin with the ./ implied when using GNU find without a search path. For example find /path/to/dir -type f ...

GNU find without file arguments, defaults to scanning ., so except for . itself, paths will contain a /, so you just need -regex '.*/[0-9]+ like in my answer. But you may also need LC_ALL=C or you may miss files in directories whose name is not valid text in the user's locale, and [0-9] outside of the C locale may match many more characters than just 0123456789

[0-9] could (and should!) be replaced by the "easy and non-surprising" [0123456789], avoiding any question on how the locale could impact it's scope
